# Cannot parse JSON object containing escape characters

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to javascript and just learning AJAX calls and parsing JSON objects so I know I'm just missing something obvious.  I can retrieve the JSON string from my API but I cannot parse it correctly.
I'm not sure if I'm sending a JSON object that cannot be parsed or just trying to read the fields in the wrong way.
Thanks for taking the time to read this and your help is greatly appreciated I'm just at a loss for where to go next.

I can get the JSON string by this.responseText but when I try to access the field Title I only get undefiend.  I'm trying to access it this way:
this.responseText.title
I've also tried:
this.responseText[title] and this.responseText["title"]

```
"{\"Id\":220,\"Title\":\"Drawtober 19\",\"YearCreated\":0,\"DatePublished\":\"2018-12-14T03:27:05.51\"}"
```

is what I get from the AJAX call and my attempt to get the title:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                let x = this.responseText;
                let firstTest = JSON.parse(x[0]);
                let secondTest = JSON.parse(x.Title);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.faithfulimagination.com/api/artwork/220", true);
        xhttp.send();
        }
```

I'm expecting to see "Drawtober 19" and all I get is 'undefined'

**EDIT**

The issue was originally in my API as Barmar pointed out.  I was calling JsonConvert.SerializeObject and returning a string rather than returning just the object.
Calling JSON.parse(x) twice worked perfectly as did fixing my API and only having to call it once.
Thank you all for answering so quickly!  It seems everyone picked up on my problem right away.

Comment: Just `let obj = JSON.parse(x);` and then you can do `obj.Title`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your response is encoded twice, so you need to decode it twice:

```
let data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(x));
let title = data.Title;
```

There's no good reason for double encoding. If faithfulimagination.com is your site, you should fix it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar!  That was the exact problem. As you suggested the issue rested originally in my API.  Calling JsonConvert.SerializeObject() and returning it as a string was double encoding it.

Comment: it helped me same for php. i was trying to decode "[\"United Arab Emirates\",\"United States\",\"Pakistan\"]" but it fail, then twice decoded it worked $jst = json_decode(json_decode($request->countries), true);

Answer (score 0):

Just use `JSON.parse(x)` to parse the full object:

```js
const x = "{\"Id\":220,\"Title\":\"Drawtober 19\",\"YearCreated\":0,\"DatePublished\":\"2018-12-14T03:27:05.51\"}";
const res = JSON.parse(x);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the response string into an object using `JSON.parse(this.responseText)`.  Your property will be on the object returned by that method.

```
JSON.parse(this.responseText).Title
```

Answer (score 0):

xhr requests returns only json string. You have to parse it to javascript object before using.
However `let firstTest = JSON.parse(x[0]);` returns only invalid because the object `x` is not an array

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                let x = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                //let firstTest = JSON.parse(x[0]); Invalid because x is not an array
                let secondTest = JSON.parse(x.Title);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.faithfulimagination.com/api/artwork/220", true);

        xhttp.send();
        }
```